# How to find all available Strings-Tables in iOS project?

Tags: swift, localization, nsbundle, nslocalizedstring

Is it possible to find all localization tables which are available in a iOS Project?

---

**Background:**

In a Swift based iOS project I am using multiple, localized `.strings` files. For example one file containing common strings used in different project, one file project specific strings, etc.

This works fine using a custom localization method which checks if a given string is found in file/table A and continues its search in file/table B if no translation is found:

```
func localizedString(forKey key: String) -> String {
    // Search in project specific, default file Localizable.strings
    var result = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: nil)

    // If now translation was found, continue search in shared file "Common.strings"
    if result == key {
        result = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: "Common")
    }

    if result == key {
        result = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: "OtherFile")
    }

    ...

    return result
}
```

Is it possible to extend this to a more general solution where I do not have to specify the files/tables manually, but where this is done automatically? This would allow to use the same code in different projects with different Strings-Files.

```
// PSEUDOCODE    
func localizedString(forKey key: String) -> String {
    for tableName in Bundle.main.allLocalizdationTables {   // DOES NOT EXIST...
        var result = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: tableName)

        if result != key {
            return result 
        }
    }

    return key
}
```

So: Is it possible to

Comment: `Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "strings", subdirectory: nil)` might help. Getting all the URLs, then extract the names of the files...

Comment: Thanks @Larme I was not aware, that the `.strings` files are actually included in the compiled Bundle but this indeed the case. If you would like to add this as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
func localizedString(forKey key: String) -> String {
    guard let filesURL = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "strings", subdirectory: nil) else { return key }
    let tablesName = filesURL.map { $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
    for aTableName in tablesName {
        var result = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: aTableName)
        if result != key {
            return result
        }
    }
    return key
}
```